# char array printing 1 char short of what I assigned

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop

I am trying to create a character array with X number of characters.

I need the first X-1 characters to be spaces and I need the Xth character to be an `*`.

I have written the following:

```
int i = 0;
int X = 5;
char spaces[X]; //In this case X is 5 so the array should have indexes 0 - 4
for(i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    spaces[i] = '*'; //I start by setting all 5 char's equal to '*'
    printf("spaces = '%s'\n", spaces); //This was to make sure it ran the correct # of times
}
```

The output of this segment is the following, the 'gh' is different every time:

```
spaces = '*gh'
spaces = '**h'
spaces = '***'
spaces = '****'
spaces = '****'
```

why does spaces only grow to 4 instead of 5 characters?
Shouldn't spaces[4] = '*'; have been called?

After setting the whole string equal to '*' I run a second for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < X-1; i++) {
    spaces[i] = ' ';
}
```

which should then set everything but the Xth character equal to ' ', but since the string is acting like its only X-1 characters long, the whole thing is set to spaces and it comes out like this

```
spaces = '    ';
```

4 spaces, when I need 4 spaces followed by an `*`.

Comment: The last character is `Null terminator` `\0`.

Comment: In fact you can use the `Xth` element to store another character but you'll get garbage output appended to your output.\

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/zHaPla)

Comment: You need more space allocated; you've not got a null terminator.  You can do the job succinctly with `char spaces[X+1]; sprintf(spaces, "%*c", X, '*');`.  This will blank pad (right justify) the `*` with `X-1` spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the string termination character `\0`, which is needed once you want to print your array as a string using `printf("%s",...)`.
So make your array one item larger than the items you want to print, and initialize it with `0`, such that everything you write into the array will at the end be a valid string. Otherwise you yield undefined behaviour:

```
int main (void)
{
#define X 5

    int i = 0;
    char spaces[X+1] = { 0 };
    for(i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        spaces[i] = '*'; 
        printf("spaces = '%s'\n", spaces); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set first X-1 characters to be spaces and the Xth character to be an *.
This will always have the last character a '*'

```
for(i = 0; i < X-1; i++) {
    spaces[i] = ' ';
    spaces[i+1] = '*'; 
    printf("spaces = '%s'\n", spaces); 
}
```

Comment: This does not null terminate the string.